# DMS task failing on full load

Tags: oracle, postgresql, aws-dms

I am trying to run DMS task from Oracle to AWS PostgreSQL. DMS task has given an error with following message on cloud watch logs,

```
    [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]E: ORA-08103: object no longer exists [1022307] (oracle_endpoint_unload.c:235)'

    [TASK_MANAGER    ]W:  Table 'schema'.'table_name' (subtask 1 thread 0) is suspended'  (replicationtask.c:2468)

    [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]I: Unload finished for table 'schema'.'table_name' (Id = 1). 217630417 rows sent. (streamcomponent.c:3473)

    [TASK_MANAGER ]I: All tables are loaded. Full load only task is stopped (replicationtask.c:3564)

    [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]I: Disconnecting Oracle database (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:1182)

    [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Disconnecting Oracle database (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:1182)

    [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]I: Disconnected Oracle database (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:1217)

    [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Disconnected Oracle database (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:1217)

    [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Subtask #1 ended (replicationtask_util.c:597)

    [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task management thread terminated (replicationtask.c:3739)`
```

My table has 220 million records with no primary keys. After validate the source and target tables still 0.2 million records are pending to migrate.

Wondering like has anyone faced same issue earlier. If anyone share the experience on troubleshoot the issue. Will be appreciated.